# Узнать информацию о материнской плате с помощью библиотеки python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Хотелось бы найти библиотеку python 3, для того, чтобы узнать информацию о материнской плате - название, номер и т.п.

Comment: таки что же мешает этим [заняться](https://toster.ru/q/339384)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[WMI](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/WMI/)

```
>>> import wmi
>>> a = wmi.WMI()
>>> a.Win32_BaseBoard()[0].SerialNumber
```

Comment: Как я понял, это только для Windows и то с определенных версий?

Comment: да. Для других платформ тоже есть такие библиотеки. По ищете google.

Answer (score 4):

Для Linux есть утилита **dmidecode** (требуется root), существует ее портированная версия под Windows.
Вызов через субпроцесс.

так же существуют ОС специфичные вызовы под определенные системы.
Подробнее можете посмотреть [в этой теме](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2461141/get-a-unique-computer-id-in-python-on-windows-and-linux)